# NullPointerException: in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I tried adding this to my map activity , but it is getting this error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Iterator com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.iterator()' on a null object reference

[image]

```java
mFireStore.collection("Locations").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
        if (error != null) {
            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "error in firebase" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        for (DocumentSnapshot doc: value) {
            String name = doc.getString("name");
            String lat = doc.getString("latitude");
            String log = doc.getString("longitude");
            double v1 = Double.parseDouble(lat);
            double v2 = Double.parseDouble(log);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(v1, v2);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(name)).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: you might not have an error, but are you sure you're getting value back from firebase ?

Answer (score 0):

The `onEvent` function will be called with *either* an error *or* a query snapshot. It will never receive both.

In your code you handle the error, but then *also* try to handle the query snapshot. That's what fails, because when you get an error you *won't* get a query snapshot.

The solution is to exit the function after handling the error:

```
@Override
public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
    if (error != null) {
        Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "error in firebase" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return; // exit after handling error
    }

    for (DocumentSnapshot doc: value) {
        String name = doc.getString("name");
        String lat = doc.getString("latitude");
        String log = doc.getString("longitude");
        double v1 = Double.parseDouble(lat);
        double v2 = Double.parseDouble(log);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(v1, v2);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(name)).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
    }
}
```